# Jira using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, jira

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2013 to create Jiras. I have installed Atlassian SDK Signed and the appropriate RestClient and RestSharpSigned and Json. When I run the app the first time, I get a dialog asking me for the location of the Issue.cs. When I run the app the second time, it asked me for the RestClient.cs file. I have checked the Atlassian dll directory but I can't find the Issue.cs file. also, the original location for this file in the dialog is c:\dev\atlassian.net-sdk\atlassian.jira\remote\jirarestclient.cs. Does anyone know what this is? Here is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Atlassian.Jira;

try
{
    var JiraInstance = Jira.CreateRestClient("http://myserver:8080/rest/api/2/issue/", "username", "password");

    var JiraIssue = JiraInstance.CreateIssue("QST");

    JiraIssue.Type = "Task";
    JiraIssue.Priority = "Major";
    JiraIssue.Summary = "PLEASE IGNORE THIS JIRA: We are Testing Jira Automation Ticket Creation.";
    JiraIssue.Description = "PLEASE IGNORE THIS JIRA: Create issue using ServiceNow Incident - SN Number - INC0592429";
    JiraIssue.Assignee = "My Name";

    JiraIssue.SaveChanges(); //SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    rtxbxError.Text = "Error - " + error;
}
```

Comment: That means that an exception is being thrown and Visual Studio is trying to break into the code to show you where it's coming from.  It can't find the source code files so it asks you to locate them.  Either run without the debugger attached or disable the "break on first chance exception feature".  You can also cancel out of the find file dialogs and just hit F5 to let the application continue running.

Comment: Programs don't ask for .cs file, the debugger does when it crashes.  Do not assume that the problem is located in Atlassian's source code.